# "could not connect to session bus" on login

Tags: 11.10, login, dbus

Just got a new Ubuntu 11.10 install working. Updated my software and rebooted, but now when I try to log in, I'm greeted with the following error:

```
could not connect to session bus: //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very weird file path `//bin/dbus-launch` - that should've been `/usr/bin/dbus-launch`. Does the system hang there or does it allow you to go further?

Have you tried searching for that path in your home?
This will go through your files/documents in home and echo the filename that contains "dbus-launch":

```
grep -ri dbus-launch /home/myusername
```

Also try creating a new user.

- Press CTRL+ALT+F1 - this will get you in the console. Login with your credentials.
- Execute:

  ```
   sudo adduser mynewuser
   sudo adduser mynewuser admin
  ```

  It will ask for a password twice, type it in. You can leave the rest of the fields empty (full name etc.), just press enter. The second command will add you as administrator.
- Now restart your lightdm (desktop manager): `sudo service lightdm restart`

If the new user works, then it's definitely a problem in your home folder (probably hidden folder settings, press ctrl+H in nautilus to show hidden files/folders).

Answer (score 0):

I have also this error because I change text in file .profile

So get to Ubuntu I use tips from:
http://www.89geek.com/2012/01/fix-ubuntu-could-not-connect-to-bus.html

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when I modified the `/etc/environment` file and changed the PATH variable.

I went to [**this**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1442849) to solve the problem.

On the login screen Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then type in your regular name and password.

If you get something like "`/bin` is unavailable" because it's not included the PATH environment then you need to go to you `/etc/environment` file and see if it looks like this

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```

I had extra lines because I was trying to add java to the path

If you type in

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

you will be able to us the ls command but that will only be for this login session

I edited that file with the pico editor

```
sudo pico /etc/environment
```

saved it, logged out and the pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to get back to the graphic log in and was able to log in.