# Error during login

Tags: 11.10, login, dbus

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and I'm new to Linux family. I have a problem with logging in to it. After I enter password and press enter it says:

```
Could not connect to session bus: //bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

According to this question ["could not connect to session bus" on login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104329/could-not-connect-to-session-bus-on-login) I tried to login as guest user and succeeded. So it's "definitely a problem with my home folder". And O think I know what the problem is.

The question is: how can I get access to my home folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post on the ubuntu forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232886.

But let's try other thing, do this;

```
sudo -i
```

then go to `/home`and do `ll`

you will see something like this:

```
:/home# ll
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  6 root    root     128 2012-01-31 09:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x 25 root    root     704 2012-02-13 07:31 ../
drwxr-xr-x 81 marcelo marcelo 3008 2012-02-20 20:08 marcelo/
drwxr-xr-x 20 test    test     784 2012-01-31 13:10 test/
```

you us what you see in yours.

in mine there are 2 users: marcelo (me) and test (for other reasons).
inside your folder do `ll` again and let's see how is the owner o that folder.

you can do (as root) `chown user folder`/ and `chgrp group folder/`

In my case to change the folder /test to me and my group "marcelo" is this way:

```
chown marcelo test/
chgrp marcelo test/
```

Hope it could be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for the post about setgid:operation not permitted. About the other thing 'sudo -i' it shows error 'unable to change to sudoers gid'.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. Since I wanted only to get access to my home folder, I used ubuntu livecd to boot and modify /home/{username} folder contents. I haven't faced all these problems that were described. As I suspected the problem with logging in happened because of incorrect configuration of pam_environment file. I used this help page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables to create file

`/home/{username}/.pam_environment`

with the following contents

`MAVEN_HOME=/home/{username}/java/maven2`

`PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH`

May be this will be helpful for somebody. How to make configuration work - I guess this is another question.

Comment: great! this could be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You can log in as guest and then execute the command `su - username` from shell (replace 'username' with your user name). It will ask you for your password and afterward you will be able to access your home directory.

Comment: This is not working. It says 'setgid: Operation not permitted'.